# How to disable any checkbox from checking if another one is checked in WinFormApp

Tags: c#, winforms

How to disable any checkbox from checking if another one is checked in WinFormApp ?
I need one at a time to be checked!

Comment: use a radio button.. so much easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you should be using radio buttons instead. To do that with check boxes you'll need to manually uncheck the boxes on the .checked event.

Answer (score 0):

Use radio buttons. If you really don't want to use them, then subscribe all checkboxes to following `CheckedChanged` event handler:

```
private void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;

    if (checkBox.Checked)
        foreach (var other in Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c != checkBox))
            other.Checked = false;
}
```